# <Show> How can I remove the DELETE button?

Tags: react-admin

I think it makes sense to remove the DELETE button from  or at least don't include by default the DELETE button. How can I remove it? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can replace the list of default actions by your own element using the actions prop: https://marmelab.com/react-admin/CreateEdit.html#actions

Comment: How about for the delete button within a list item ? Because actions seems to work only for bulk actions.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't quite understand your question, for forms like Edit / Show this is implemented through the implementation of the actions property,
in List rows, you just need to remove the child component DeleteButton.

Comment: How do you remove `<DeleteButton />` in `List`, to me, I can add some `<DeleteButton />` by using it in the `<DataGrid>`, but if I put none, it always get displayed.

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of this situation?

Comment: In a table, you have rows, on each rows, you can have button such as View/Edit/Delete, to me, View and Edit are created when I add the button in the grid, but not delete which is always present. I don't think if you have ever heard about react-admin, that a screen shot is necessary to show a standard feature

Comment: This screenshot show the button in RA: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56902946/react-admin-how-to-show-delete-button-on-each-row-in-datagrid

Comment: Strange, I have these buttons created only if I myself add a child component DeleteButton to the set of fields, I do not specifically delete them in any way.

Comment: Interesting, If I add a child, then I have two.

Comment: Are you using a standard Datagrid, not your own implementation?

Comment: I use the standard