# react-admin: How to show Delete button on each row in Datagrid

Tags: reactjs, react-admin

I would like to have Datagrid with `Delete` button as below (picture is copied from stackoverflow.com):

[image: Datagrid with Delete button]

I read react-admin documents but did not find any hints to add a `Delete` button onto the row.
Any body know how to?

Thanks,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is as simple as importing and adding the  to your listview:

```
import { Datagrid, TextField, EditButton, DeleteButton } from 'react-admin';
export const SaleList = props => (
    <List {...props}>
        <Datagrid>
            <TextField source="id"/>
            <EditButton/>
            <DeleteButton/>
        </Datagrid>
    </List>
);
```